# Multiplication and division by a morphism under the “inner composition” in closed monoidal categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, counterexamples, enriched-category-theory

I asked this a week ago at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271110/multiplication-and-division-by-a-morphism-under-the-inner-composition-in-close), without success, so I hope it will be appropriate here.

Let ${\mathcal C}$ be a symmetric [closed monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category), and let me denote the internal hom-functor by a fraction
$$
(X,Y)\mapsto\frac{Y}{X},
$$
so that we have an isomorphism of functors
$$
\operatorname{Mor}(A\otimes B,C)\cong \operatorname{Mor}\left(A,\frac{C}{B}\right).
$$
As is known, ${\mathcal C}$ is an [enriched category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category+theory) over itself. For each objects $A,B,C$ let me denote by $\bullet_{A,B,C}$ the "inner composition" in ${\mathcal C}$ as in an enriched category, i.e. the morphism 
$$
\bullet_{A,B,C}:\frac{C}{B}\otimes\frac{B}{A}\to\frac{C}{A}
$$
with the corresponding properties.

> I wonder if the following identity always holds
>   $$
> \bullet_{A,C,D}\circ\left(1_{\frac{D}{C}}\otimes\frac{\varphi}{1_A}\right)= 
> \bullet_{A,B,D}\circ\left(\frac{1_D}{\varphi}\otimes1_{\frac{B}{A}}\right)
> $$
>   (for arbitrary objects $A,B,C,D$ and for arbitrary morphism $\varphi:B\to C$).

[image: multiplication and division by a morphism under the inner multiplication]

This is strange, I can prove this only in the case when [the unit $I$ is a separating object in ${\mathcal C}$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator#definitions) (what [does not always hold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246600/is-the-unit-object-in-a-closed-monoidal-category-always-integral/3246610#3246610)). Is it possible that there is a counterexample?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this equation follows from the axioms of closed monoidal categories. I think the easiest way to prove this is to show that the corresponding pair of multimaps $\frac{D}{C}, \frac{B}{A} \to \frac{D}{A}$ are equal in any [closed multicategory](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3137), which you can do by expressing them as (ordered linear) lambda terms and checking that they have the same normal form.

Let $b:B \vdash \varphi:C$ be an arbitrary term with one free variable $b$.
Define two terms $t_1$ and $t_2$ of type
$$
f:\frac{D}{C}, g:\frac{B}{A} \vdash t_i : \frac{D}{A}
$$
by
$$
t_1 := \lambda a.f ((\lambda a'.\varphi[g(a')/b])a)
$$
$$
t_2 := \lambda a.(\lambda b'.f (\varphi[b'/b]))(g(a))
$$
where "$t[u/x]$" denotes the capture-avoiding substitution of the term $u$ for the variable $x$ in $t$.
These correspond to the two morphisms $\bullet_{A,C,D}\circ\left(1_{\frac{D}{C}}\otimes\frac{\varphi}{1_A}\right)$ and $\bullet_{A,B,D}\circ\left(\frac{1_D}{\varphi}\otimes1_{\frac{B}{A}}\right)$, respectively,
but both $t_1$ and $t_2$ normalize (after one $\beta$-reduction) to the same term
$$
t = \lambda a.f (\varphi[g(a)/b])
$$
which proves that the two morphisms are equivalent modulo the equations of closed monoidal categories.

(In the above I have been implicitly treating your $\otimes$ as a comma, but if we want to be completely rigorous about this we can work with a closed *representable* multicategory.)

Comment: Re: the last parenthetical, this equation can actually be generalized to any closed (not necessarily monoidal) category after currying the two morphisms to have type $\frac CB \to \frac{\frac CA}{\frac CB}$.  The argument above still works, with the two corresponding terms reducing to the same normal form $\lambda g.\lambda a.f(\phi[g(a)/b])$.

Comment: (that should be "type $\frac DC \to \frac{\frac DA}{\frac BA}$")

Comment: Noam, this is something new for me, I need some time to understand this.

Answer (score 7):

Noam’s answer is already good and complete, but here is alternate answer phrased more elementarily in terms of the symmetric monoidal category structure.  We want to show

$$\bullet_{A,C,D}\circ\left(1_{[C,D]}\otimes[1_A,\varphi]\right)= 
\bullet_{A,B,D}\circ\left([\varphi,1_D]\otimes 1_{[A,B]}\right) : [C,D] \otimes [A,B] \to [A,D] $$

It’s enough to show their corresponding exponential transpose maps $[C,D] \otimes [A,B] \otimes A \to D$ agree.  But for these, we have:

$$ \newcommand{\ev}{\operatorname{ev}} 
\ev_{A,D} \circ \left( (\bullet_{A,C,D} \circ(1_{[C,D]}\otimes[1_A,\varphi])) \otimes 1_A \right) \\
= \ev_{A,D} \circ (\bullet_{A,C,D} \otimes 1_A)\circ\left(1_{[C,D]}\otimes[1_A,\varphi] \otimes 1_A\right) \\
= \ev_{C,D} \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes \ev_{A,C})\circ \left(1_{[C,D]}\otimes[1_A,\varphi] \otimes 1_A\right) \\
= \ev_{C,D} \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes (\ev_{A,C} \circ ([1_A,\varphi] \otimes 1_A)))
\\
= \ev_{C,D} \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes (\varphi \circ \ev_{A,B})) \\
= \ev_{C,D} \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes \varphi) \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes \ev_{A,B})
 $$

and a similar calculation shows 
$$ \ev_{A,D} \circ \left( (\bullet_{A,B,D}\circ([\varphi,1_D]\otimes 1_{[A,B]})) \otimes 1_A \right)  = \ev_{C,D} \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes \varphi) \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes \ev_{A,B}).$$

Each step is just using either the monoidal category laws, or the fact that the maps $\bullet_{A,C,D}$, $[1_A,\varphi]$ are defined by their exponential transpose maps.

(Please excuse my using the notation $[A,B]$ for mapping objects, since I’m more familiar with it than the fraction notation $\frac{B}{A}$.)

Comment: Peter, I don't understand why the second calculation gives the same result.

Comment: Notice that in the first calculation, the two key steps use the equalities $ev_{A,D}( \bullet_{A,C,D} \otimes 1_A) = ev_{C,D} \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes ev_{A,C})$ and $ev_{A,C} \circ ([1_A,\varphi] \otimes 1_A) = \varphi \circ ev_{A,B}$.  These equalities are essentially the *definitions* of $\bullet_{A,C,D}$ and $[1_A,\varphi]$ in terms of their exponential transpose maps.  All other steps are just monoidal category laws.  The second calculation is very analogous, but its two key steps use the defining equalities of $\bullet_{A,B,D}$ and $[\varphi,1_D]$.

Comment: I don't understand something. I come to the result $\operatorname{ev}_{B,D}\circ[\varphi,1_D]\otimes\operatorname{ev}_{A,B}$. Why is this equal to $\operatorname{ev}_{C,D} \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes \varphi) \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes\operatorname{ev}_{A,B})$?

Comment: In the result you reached, split up $([\varphi,1_D] \otimes ev_{A,B})$ as $([\varphi,1_D] \otimes 1_B) \circ (1_{[C,D]} \otimes ev_{A,B})$, and then use the defining equation of $[\varphi,1_D]$.  The way to find this is to notice that you should expect to need the defining equation of $[\varphi,1_D]$, so look at that equation, and then try to think how to get your result into a form where you can use that equation.

Comment: Peter, I feel like a schoolboy near you. :) As far as I understand, you call this  $$\operatorname{ev}_{B,D}\circ([\varphi,1_D]\otimes 1_B)=\operatorname{ev}_{C,D}\circ(1_{[C,D]}\otimes\varphi)$$ -- the defining equation for $[\varphi,1_D]$. Excuse me my ignorance, why is this true? (Actually, in my understanding the operation $(A,B)\mapsto [A,B]$ is not defined, it is introduced axiomatically, so this identity must be proved.)

Comment: Yes, that is the equation I meant by “the defining equation for $[\varphi,1_D]$”.  If the operation $[A,B]$ is introduced as characterised by its universal property, then the operation sending $f : X' \to X$ and $g : Y \to Y'$ to $[f,g] : [X,Y] \to [X',Y']$ is usually defined as “the map corresponding to $g \circ ev_{X',Y} \circ (1_[X,Y] \otimes f) : [X,Y] \otimes X' \to Y'$”, in other words by the equation $ev_{X',Y'} \circ ([f,g] \otimes 1_{Y'}) = g \circ ev_{X',Y} \circ (1_[X,Y] \otimes f)$.  If the operation $[f,g]$ is introduced/assumed some other way (e.g. functoriality), then [cont’d]

Comment: …then that equation must proved some other way, e.g. by naturality, or the unit/counit equations of the adjunction, or similar.  There are many equivalent ways to present the internal hom-functor, coming (in part) from the different ways to present adjunctions, and the fact that adjoints are automatically functorial when they exist.

Comment: Peter, this is where the misunderstanding lies. I was asking about a general symmetric closed monoidal category, which I understand in the sense of usual definition, i.e. a category with the given functors $\otimes$ and $[\cdot,\cdot]$. You seem to have in mind another definition (which I don't know), where $\operatorname{ev}_{\cdot,\cdot}$ is given (and axiomatized) instead of $[\cdot,\cdot]$. So for me this equation requires a proof.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: We are both talking about the “usual definition” — the point is that this definition can be presented in several slightly different ways, but the equivalences between them are very standard, and so the differences are not usually thought of as significant.  Specifically, I’m assuming the definition given [at the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category): that there’s a natural bijection $\psi_{X,Y,Z} : C(X,[Y,Z]) \cong C(X \otimes Y, Z)$. [cont’d]

Comment: Given this, I am taking $ev_{X,Y} : [X,Y] \otimes X \to Y$ to be the map corresponding to $1_{[X,Y]}$ under $\psi_{[X,Y],X,Y}$.  It follows by naturality that for arbitrary $X,Y,Z$, the bijection $\psi_{X,Y,Z}$ sends $f : X \to [Y,Z]$ to $ev_{Y,Z} \circ (f \otimes 1_Y) : X \otimes Y \to Z$.  Whatever other presentation of the definition you are using, you should be able to prove that it gives this definition; the proof should roughly be like the proofs that different definitions of adjoint are equivalent, as discussed at e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor

Comment: If you’re not familiar with the equivalence between these different definitions, I really recommend working them out yourself — it’s a very useful exercise, and the equivalence is used implicitly all over the place (like I was using it here).  But if it’s still unclear, then I suggest asking a new question at math.SE about it — we’ve gone on a bit too long in comments here :-)

Comment: Peter, I understood this at last! This follows from the two identities that must be proved separately:
$$
\psi^{-1}_{A',B',C'}\big(\gamma\circ\omega\circ(\alpha\otimes\beta)\big)=[\beta,\gamma]\circ\psi^{-1}_{A,B,C}(\omega)\circ\alpha
$$
and 
$$
\psi^{-1}_{X,A,B}\left(\operatorname{ev}^B_A\circ\ (\varphi\otimes 1_A)\right)=\varphi.
$$
However your words about "different definitions" remain puzzling  for me, I think, the explanation will be crearer without them.

Comment: Now all we need is for someone to give a proof with string diagrams!